I created an exe file using pyinstaller. When there is a DLL file at the same level as the exe file, an exception will occur
I developed an application using PyQt5 and packaged it into a standalone exe file using pyinstaller's one-file mode。
The packaging process is successful, and independent execution is also okay. But when Qt5Core.dll(may be other qt dlls) appears in the same directory of the exe file, The following error occurred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestCollectionEditor.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtGui: 找不到指定的模块。


If the DLL file is removed, it can be successfully executed again. Will the DLL file in the same directory be loaded when executing ?
package the exe with not one-file mode, copy the qt dll to the same directory, got the exception too.

DLLs are searched with priorities: the first path used for research is the working dir (the context path in which the program is executed), which normally is the same in which the executable is. See if the answers to this post help  you: pyinstaller fails to load a dll that is present.
